# Is it possible to fix XML / SVG by adding proper namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, svg

I have following SVG build in Inkscape and as you can see it is missing SVG Namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg width="1000" height="715" id="svg2" p1:version="0.32" p2:version="0.46" version="1.0" p2:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape" xmlns:p1="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:p2="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
  <defs id="defs4">
    <perspective p1:type="inkscape:persp3d" p2:vp_x="0 : 526.18109 : 1" p2:vp_y="0 : 1000 : 0" p2:vp_z="744.09448 : 526.18109 : 1" p2:persp3d-origin="372.04724 : 350.78739 : 1" id="perspective10" />
    <perspective id="perspective2447" p2:persp3d-origin="372.04724 : 350.78739 : 1" p2:vp_z="744.09448 : 526.18109 : 1" p2:vp_y="0 : 1000 : 0" p2:vp_x="0 : 526.18109 : 1" p1:type="inkscape:persp3d" />
    <perspective id="perspective3327" p2:persp3d-origin="372.04724 : 350.78739 : 1" p2:vp_z="744.09448 : 526.18109 : 1" p2:vp_y="0 : 1000 : 0" p2:vp_x="0 : 526.18109 : 1" p1:type="inkscape:persp3d" />
  </defs>
  <namedview id="base" pagecolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1.0" gridtolerance="10000" guidetolerance="10" objecttolerance="10" p2:pageopacity="0.0" p2:pageshadow="2" p2:zoom="7" p2:cx="324.34286" p2:cy="238.59584" p2:document-units="px" p2:current-layer="svg2" showgrid="false" p2:window-width="1020" p2:window-height="718" p2:window-x="0" p2:window-y="14" />
  <metadata id="metadata7">
    <RDF>
      <Work p6:about="" xmlns:p6="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
        <format>image/svg+xml</format>
        <type p6:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </Work>
    </RDF>
  </metadata>
    <rect style="opacity:0.92000002;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.00288939;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" id="rect2473" width="172.33044" height="88.997108" x="419.00143" y="315.00143" rx="0.30000001" ry="0.30000001" />
</svg>
```

Following XSLT transformation is used for stripping out all unnecessary information:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0""
    xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"" 
    xmlns:svg=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"">

    <!-- Any element matching svg namespace is copied. -->
    <xsl:template match=""svg:*"">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select=""@*[namespace-uri()='']""/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=""node()""/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Default: Exclude element -->
    <xsl:template match=""*""/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When XSLT transformation is run it produces empty XML because from what I understand SVG Namespace is missing in Root node.

So my question is if it is possible to fix that somehow? I did try to add namespace to document's Root node but it won't help.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the expected result of the transformation?

Comment: This doesn't validate as svg in the first place, there are no elements called `<namedview>` or `<perspective>` in svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet will copy all elements and attributes that are in the default no-namespace of the source document, and place them in the SVG namespace:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[not(namespace-uri())]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(namespace-uri())]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="715" id="svg2" version="1.0">
   <defs id="defs4">
      <perspective id="perspective10"/>
      <perspective id="perspective2447"/>
      <perspective id="perspective3327"/>
   </defs>
   <namedview id="base" pagecolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1.0" gridtolerance="10000" guidetolerance="10" objecttolerance="10" showgrid="false"/>
   <metadata id="metadata7">
      <RDF>
         <Work>
            <format>image/svg+xml</format>
            <type/>
         </Work>
      </RDF>
   </metadata>
   <rect style="opacity:0.92000002;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.00288939;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" id="rect2473" width="172.33044" height="88.997108" x="419.00143" y="315.00143" rx="0.30000001" ry="0.30000001"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the whole idea of using that XSLT is to remove non-SVG elements from original source. With XLST you provided it won't do that.

Comment: @Hayk You have to provide a criteria for identifying SVG (or non-SVG) elements. -- Just FYI: the result of the above transformation renders as SVG in a browser - non-SVG elements notwithstanding.

Comment: SVG criteria is defined by "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" namespace. While produced XML will render in browser it will include elements that are not par of SVG namespace, for example RDF, Work etc. The goal was to clean source XML so only elements that are part of the SVG namespace are included in final version.

Comment: @Hayk I am afraid we are not on the same page. The problem with your input is that the SVG elements are in no-namespace, instead of being in the SVG namespace. The solution above places **all** no-namespace elements of the source document in the SVG namespace (and removes elements in other namespaces). In order to place only *some* elements in the SVG namespace, the stylesheet would have to "know" which elements are SVG and which are not. This information is not available in your input - so without further input this task is impossible.

Comment: P.S. I have Inkscape on my computer and when I save a file, all the elements are in their proper namespaces.

Comment: I guess you are correct. My goal is to get an SVG without any element which is not affecting end result, for example "defs", "namedview" etc. Is that possible?

Comment: The only way, IMHO, is to supply a list of element names used by the SVG schema. But even that is not 100% foolproof, as it is perfectly permissible for a document to use the same element name under two namespaces for two different purposes (that's the whole point of namespaces). The real issue here is that your input has lost some information - and this information cannot be reconstructed. Could you not solve this problem upstream?

Comment: Not sure what "upstream" means?

Comment: Where the input is being produced. You mentioned Inkscape as the source - but as I have already written, Inkscape doesn't do that.